# How to update PCRE in CENTOS/Redhat 6

Tags: php, linux, centos, wikipedia, centos6

For installing Scribunto, a Mediawiki add ins, it requires at least PCRE version 8.1. But in CENTOS update, the maximum version is 7.8.

I compiled the source code version 8.33 successfully and with "pcretest -C" command, it is already version 8.33. But the phpinfo() has still the old PCRE 7.8.

**How to point PCRE in php to the newest version?**

Comment: Where did your own version of libpcre install to? Try to prioritize it via `ld.so.conf` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or utilize `LD_PRELOAD=` to specifically run Apache/PHP just with your custom pcre build.

Comment: I installed to /usr. I am newbie for this field. I know ld.so.conf but I don't know LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_PRELOAD. I don't know how to find from where php get the pcre. Step by step command line is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sigh*.

I feel ya.

I can tell you that what finally worked for me was building PCRE [from source](http://pcre.org/) and using FastCGI (the `mod_fcgid` package in CentOS 6) with a stanza like this in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`:

```
<IfModule fcgid_module>
  SetEnv LD_PRELOAD /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1

  ScriptAlias /fcgi-bin/ /var/www/fcgi-bin/
  AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp .php
  Action application/x-httpd-fastphp /fcgi-bin/php-cgi

  <Directory /var/www/fcgi-bin/>
    # Allows /usr/bin/php-cgi to be symlinked here
    Options +FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Here are a list of things I tried with the default "modular" PHP setup (`php5_module`) before giving up and resorting to FastCGI.

- `PassEnv LD_PRELOAD` with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1` defined in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.
- `SetEnv LD_PRELOAD /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1`
- `LoadFile /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1`

**However**, I was putting these directives inside `VirtualHost` sections, generally, so I won't rule out the possibility that *order* was the problem. That is, it's entirely possible that these directives would need to come *before* the PHP module was loaded, and I wasn't doing that. I was using an `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and a `vhosts.conf` and generally trying not to sully the top-level config file while I was experimenting.

Eventually I ran out of patience and tried going the FCGI route, and that worked for me. If you're married to running PHP as a loadable module, then you may wish to try some of the above options with things like `LoadFile` specified in `httpd.conf` *before* the PHP DSO is loaded.

Comment: Actually I have solved this problem by upgrading Centos 6 to 7 that didn't exist when I asked this question. But thank you for the answer.